# How get tones(analyze) from .wav? with SDL

Tags: c, audio, sdl, wav

I have soundtrack .wav with generated tones. And I found SDL code for reading it:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    SDL_AudioSpec wav_spec;
    Uint32 wav_length;
    Uint8 *wav_buffer;

    /* Load the WAV */
    if (SDL_LoadWAV("test.wav", &wav_spec, &wav_buffer, &wav_length) == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Could not open test.wav: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    } else {
      
        
        SDL_FreeWAV(wav_buffer);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How I can handle changes of tones in `wav_buffer`?

Comment: Are you looking for [the FFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43479528/how-can-i-perform-a-realtime-fft-on-sdl2-audio-stream-data)?

Comment: @Nelfeal thanks, it's helpfull. but i thought i can make it in simple way